# How to use Flutter MethodChannel from FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-method-channel

I'm using [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) `onBackgroundMessage` handler for listening push messages and it works as expected. Now I want to call platform method from this handler, but I'm unable to do this. [MethodChannel](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) can only be registered to Android Activity, but there is no Activity at this point. I was able solve my problem by creating custom Flutter plugin and implementing MethodChannel there, but this has some problems:

- Have to manage separate plugin code - unnecessary boilerplate and effort
- Hard to communicate between host application code and plugin code (e.g. wanting to use some method that is implemented on platform side in host application).

So the question is: is it possible to achieve same thing without plugin (e.g. create MethodChannel and register it globally). If it is possible for plugins, it should be possible for main application as well. Currently I only need to cover Android, if this makes things easier.

Comment: do you try to use AwesomeNotifications ?

Comment: No, I'm not trying to use AwesomeNotifications

Comment: I ended up creating a plugin. In `onCreate` method in Application.kt, I registered callback so that in a round about way I arrive my "main" application: isolate calls plugin's method channel, this calls callback registered in Application.onCreate and from there I can do other stuff (e.g. startActivity)